# Return Named Array in Ajax Request

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I am trying to pass back an array with named indexes (e. g.: data.sugg_id) for a post request. This is how my javascript / jQuery looks like:

```
$.post('submit_text.php', JSON.stringify({'unit_id' : unit_id,
                                            'text' : text,
                                            'ignore_warnings' : ignore_warnings
                                            }), 
        function(data) {
            sugg_id = data.sugg_id;

            if (data.status == 'failure') {
                warning_history = {}
                showMessage(errorBox, data.message);
                warnBox.fadeOut("fast");
            }
```

My submit_text.php looks like:

```
<?
    header("Content-Type: application/json");

    $unit_id = $_POST["unit_id"];
    $text = $_POST["text"];
    $ignore_warnings = $_POST["ignore_warnings"];

    $sugg_id = 24;
    //$status = "success";
    $status = $text;
    $message = "";
    $data = array("sugg_id" => $sugg_id, "status" => $status, "message" => $message);
    echo json_encode($data);
?>
```

I tried to use alert(data.status) but it said "undefined". What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What's the output if you `alert(data)`? If it has data, probably it's still in json form so you need to parse it like `data = JSON.parse(data);`.

Comment: Pass datatype `json` to `$.post()` method

Comment: did you specified the as Content-Type: application/json in your php script

Comment: what does your console display?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested by @A. Wolff pass `dataType`

```
$.post('submit_text.php', JSON.stringify({'unit_id' : unit_id,
                                            'text' : text,
                                            'ignore_warnings' : ignore_warnings
                                            }), 
        function(data) {
            sugg_id = data.sugg_id;

            if (data.status == 'failure') {
                warning_history = {}
                showMessage(errorBox, data.message);
                warnBox.fadeOut("fast");
            }
}, "json");
```